# How to print or log the value of UIView frame in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, uilabel, xcode7

In my application used one UILabel control.I want to print the frame(x,y,width,height) values of that label in my console.In objective c i used NSStringFromCGRect function to print the values.How to get those values in my console with swift?Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)
let label = UILabel(frame: rect)

print(label.frame)
```

prints (0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)

Answer (score 2):

Its simple

```
 print(yourLabel.frame)
```